# Quickbooks 2009 2010

Tags: import, quickbooks

I have configured my bank account within quickbooks to import bank statements.  I have wxported the bank statement. Then used the convert process available within QB to convert.
The file name shows the bsb then some other figures and then the account number.  However it will not import.  I am wondering how ot make this work.  Can I change the file name to match my QB account details and thus enable the importing.   This is a technical question. Many thanks Bronwyn

Comment: what operating system?